# XCopy error code doesnt tally

Tags: command-line, batch, task-scheduler, xcopy

i have a xcpoy command which copying content in a folder to another directory via Windows Task Scheduler. However, recently we noticed there were not some events, the xcopy doesnt really copying / transfering files out. From the History of Task Scheduler, the task started and completed without any error so i amended the batch file with xcopy xxxxx >> c:\log.txt /Y

NOw i have log files that could tell me if there was any files being copied or not but still missing the reasons why it did not copied at the first place.
From Task Scheduler > History, i see the action completed with code 0 which i think it is refering to the errorcode 0 = Files were copied without error. but indeed there was no files being copied at all.

I tested trying to run the xcopy to another drive with less disk space (whereby it should be failed if im transfering file bigger than the available free space. Yet the same error code = 0 shown in the Task Scheduler > History.
When i run manually the batch file, i will show me error "insufficient disk space from the command prompt.

Question :
1) Is it possible to use xcopy and export the content from the command prompt to log file whenever the batch file is running / being triggered ?

2) how can we clearly confirmed the errorcode shown at Task Scheduler > History depicting correct code tho. ?

0   Files were copied without error.
  1   No files were found to copy.
  2   The user pressed CTRL+C to terminate xcopy.
  4   Initialization error occurred. There is not
      enough memory or disk space, or you entered
      an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on
      the command line.
  5   Disk write error occurred.

Possible to retain the code of xcopy instead of robocopy as i believe robocopy contains more details on log files but unfortunetely my client refuses to do so.

Thank you

Comment: *i see the action completed with code 0 which i think it is refering to the errorcode 0 = Files were copied without error.*  NO. Action is running batch file. Error code 0 means the batch was successfully running (no batch file text error, no cmd.exe error, etc.). The error while running executable in batch is not the error of batch. You can test each command in batch for error code, store it in some environment variable replacing default (assigned in first batch command) zero, and set proper batch exit code in the last `EXIT %errorcode%` command. Or write log immediately in batch commands.

Comment: Hi Akina, Thanks for the clarification.
On top of the log file, basically i created something like this 

time start : 21/03/2019 14:38:58.26
service stopped : 21/03/2019 14:39:00.98
c:\abc.db
0 File(s) copied
transfer completed  : 21/03/2019 14:39:01.48
service started : 21/03/2019 14:39:08.57
time completed : 21/03/2019 14:39:08.59

Comment: If there is / are files being copied .. the log would have look like this 
C:\abc.db
1 File(s) copied

Was wondering if when there is no file - 0 File copied, how could we captured the report / messages from cmd to log file ? is it possible ?